# How to read a returned Rust dll pointer from Python

Tags: python, arrays, rust, ffi, dereference

I want to return a f64 vector from Rust to Python and I'm not sure how to dereference the returned pointer in Python side.

**lib.rs**

```
use libc::c_double;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn give_me_array() -> *const Vec<c_double> {

    let array_to_pass = vec![1.05, 1.07, 2.48];    // Just an example... there are some calculations here

    &array_to_pass

}
```

**requesting_array.py**

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef("""
    double* give_me_array();
""")

dll = ffi.dlopen("...path_to_dll...")
returned_array = dll.give_me_array()
print(returned_array)
```

The output is a memory location:

```
<cdata 'double *' 0x00000....>
```

Expected output:
1.05, 1.07, 2.48

How to dereference the array in the python side?
Is this the best approach to pass a variable sized vector from Rust to Python?

**Rust-side solution by Aiden4 and modifications on Python side**

**lib.rs**

```
use libc; // 0.2.93

#[repr(C)]
pub struct CDoubleArray {
    pub ptr: *mut libc::c_double,
    pub len: usize,
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn give_me_array() -> CDoubleArray {
    let vec = vec![1.05, 1.07, 2.48];
    let len = vec.len();
    CDoubleArray {
        ptr: vec.leak().as_mut_ptr(), //leaked so the caller is responsible for the memory
        len,
    }
}
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn free_array(arr: CDoubleArray) {
    // since the caller is responsible for the memory we have to provide a way to free it
    Vec::from_raw_parts(arr.ptr, arr.len, arr.len);
}
```

**requesting_array.py**

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef("""

    typedef struct {
        double *v2_ptr;
        unsigned long v2_size;
    } CDoubleArray;

    CDoubleArray give_me_array();
    void free_array(CDoubleArray);
    
""")

dll = ffi.dlopen("...path_to.dll...")
returned_array = ffi.new("CDoubleArray *")
returned_array = dll.give_me_array()

for n in range(returned_array.v2_size):
    print(returned_array.v2_ptr[n])
```

Comment: I don't know enough about ffi to answer your question but you should never return a `Vec` (or a pointer to one). You should be instead returning a pointer to the raw data and the length, and putting it back together with python's appropriate data type.

Comment: @Aiden4 why not? How to implement your suggestion? Resturning a struct with the pointer and a usize?

Comment: Only `#[repr(C)]` structs and primitive types are ffi safe because only they provide layout guarantees. `Vec` isn't one of those, and there is no guarantee that even `Vec<Foo>` and `Vec<Bar>` are the same. And yes, returning a `#Repr(C)]` struct with a pointer and a length would be the best way.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to implement that?

Comment: The rust side might  look like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a9c3191115af85f1ad1d896af78b0f0)

Comment: Thank you! I edited the solution. It worked well for me.